# Activity Main Drawer Bug

Tags: xml, layout, navigation-drawer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqz0c.jpg)this is my Code for the Activity Main Drawer in My Adnroid Studio App.

But as you can see in the attached Photo, that the Menupoint 1 -5 are in Bolt Style. But thats only the case if im using the menu. If i restart the app. The option are in "fine" line again, but if i click on one Fragment and open the menu bar again, the options 1 -5 are again in Bolt Style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_fach"
        android:icon="@drawable/bild10"
        android:title="@string/menu_fach"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rechner"
        android:icon="@drawable/bild88"
        android:title="@string/Rezeptrechner"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_spenden"
        android:icon="@drawable/bild12"
        android:title="@string/menu_spenden"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />

    <item
        android:id="@id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/bild11"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fair" />
</menu
```

Why and How?

I tried to Change the Font in the Activity Main Drawer, and i tried to declare the items as "Fine".
I gtried to change the Style in the themes.xml